# Efficiency of nested for-loops with vastly different counts

Tags: performance, loops, for-loop

Given `a` is much larger than `b`, would

```
for (i = 0; i < a; i++)
    for (k = 0 k < b; k++)
```

be faster than

```
for (i = 0; i < b; i++)
    for (k = 0 k < a; k++)
```

It feels to me the former would be faster but I cannot seem to get my head around this.

Comment: That depends on what's inside the loop, doesn't it? You need to show what you plan to run inside the loops in question.

Comment: It's the difference between `a*b` and `b*a` - i.e. nothing.

Comment: @Blorgbeard It may not be nothing if it the content of the loop involves accessing `foo[i][k]`, for example, and one order causes a column-major iteration (which is slower). But, it really depends on the specifics of what's being done in the loop.

Comment: Sure, there's lots of reasons one would be faster than the other if you add more code, but given the information in the question, there's no difference.

Comment: @Blorgbeard: Actually, the second version might have fewer branch misspredictions, so if the body of the loop is really agnostic to it I'd take the second version.

Comment: Btw. Intels compiler (maybe others too) is sometimes able to change the loop order if it thinks beneficial - I'm not sure howwever, whether this works outside of simple matrix multiplications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it really depends on what your doing. It's hard to do runtime analysis without knowing what's being done. That being said, if your using this code to traverse through a large array, its more important to go through each column in each row rather than visa-versa.

[0][1][2]

[3][4][5]

[6][7][8]

is really [0][1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8] in memory.

Your computer's cache provides a greater advantage when memory access is close together, and going sequentially though memory rather than skipping through rows provide much more locality.

Answer (score 1):

Starting a loop takes effort; there's the loop variable itself plus al the variables declared within the loop, which are all allocated memory and pushed onto the stack.

This means the fewer times you *enter* a loop the better, so loop over the *smaller* range in the *outer* loop.